# Water from sink cuts off intermittently

Tags: water, faucet

Laundry room sink faucet ( hot or cold) will stop running for no reason. I turn faucet off stand there a couple minutes, turn water back and it works. This problem started about 3 weeks ago, no noises or anything. It just stops.

Comment: did you pay the water bill :P

Comment: It could be that the aerator is plugged somehow.

Comment: do you have a water filtration system

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll spend a few moments to take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Question & Answer forum and a little different than a general discussion board. Please [edit] your question to give us as many details as possible, including things like recent work done on your house or city plumbing, are you on city or well water, is this sink in the basement or ground floor, etc. Also, please reformulate to actually _ask_ us a question that we can answer - as it is, this is just a statement of some facts.

Comment: Unscrew the aerator and remove, and see if the water turns off again.  With it being both hot and cold, should mean that the problem is in the faucet/taps and not the plumbing pipes supplying water.